# Meaning of "en + infinitive" in "en explorar"

Tags: verbos

What is this phrase *en explorar* in the following sentence?

> Los primeros europeos **en explorar** la región del actual Illinois fueron misioneros franceses.

I would have thought you would say *que exploraron*, if the intended meaning is "The first europeans to explore...".

The construction seems to be *en* + [infinitive]. Is this correct? Can you provide other examples where "en" is used in a similar way?

Comment: I wasn't sure what tag to use, so I went with the most general I could think of.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that in Spanish, the infinitive form of a verb is used when the verb is used as a noun, where as in English, it is often used in the gerund form.  Thus, the sentence translates to English as:

> The first Europeans **in exploring** the current region of Illinois were French missionaries.

Your suggestion of *que exploraron* would be valid, too, but changes the nature of the phrase slightly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "verb as a noun" comment. In your english translation, I don't think the gerund is really being thought of as a noun, it's just a tense indicating an ongoing action, and "in" basically means "during".

Comment: @JackM: Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun).  English has the same construct as Spanish, too--that is to use the infinitive ('to explore'), but has more diversity than Spanish in this regard. In English one can say, for instance, "Swimming is fun" as well as "To swim is fun." In Spanish, only "Nadar es divertido" is accepted and "Nadando es divertido" is non-grammatical.

Comment: @Flimzy: using the infinitive and the -ing form in English is slightly different. An English teacher of mine used this example: *I like to work but I don't like working*.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the `en` preposition would translate to something along the lines of

> The first Europeans to be involved in the exploration of.....